# Cauchy Sequence if $|s_{n+1} - s_n| < 2^{-n}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, cauchy-sequences, geometric-progressions

Let $s_n$ be a sequence such that

$|s_{n+1} - s_n| < 2^{-n}$

for all $n \in N$. Prove $s_n$ is a Cauchy sequence and hence a convergent sequence.

Here's what I've started with:

Proof:

Take $\epsilon > 0$. Let $N = -\log_2{\epsilon/2}$. Thus,

$ |s_{n+1} - s_n| < 2^{\log_2{\epsilon/2}} = \epsilon/2$

I can't seem to show from this that:

$ |s_m - s_n| <\epsilon$

Some ideas relating to geometric series of $\epsilon/2 + \epsilon/4 ... \epsilon/{2^n} < \epsilon$ are springing up in my mind, but I can't really pin it to the ground (and, I'm not sure if its fair play to use the infinite series formula in this case).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a sketch; check the details carefully. You need to show that for all $\epsilon > 0$ that there is an $N$ such that for $n,m > N$, $|s_n - s_m| < \epsilon$. Let $\epsilon > 0$ be given. We have to find $N$.

Assume that $m > n$ without loss of generality. Then by the triangle inequality and the given property of the sequence, 
$$|s_m - s_n| < \frac{1}{2^m} + \cdots + \frac{1}{2^n} = \frac{1}{2^m}\left(1+\frac{1}{2} + \cdots + \frac{1}{2^{n-m}}\right)$$
and so by the formula for a geometric series,
$$|s_m - s_n| < \frac{1}{2^m} \frac{1-\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{n-m}}{1 - \frac{1}{2}} < \frac{1}{2^{m-1}}$$

Now just take $N = \log_2{\epsilon}$. Then for $m > n > N$, we have that
$$|s_m - s_n| < \frac{1}{2^{m-1}} \leq \frac{1}{2^N} = \epsilon$$

Comment: That's basically exactly what I was thinking of (except I expanded a bit on the triangle inequality concept). However, is it okay to use the geometric series formula to show something a Cauchy series?

Comment: Yes, we only used the finite geometric series, so it's fine. The infinite case would be fine as well, as long as you had verified it beforehand. You were definitely close already...

Comment: Thank you for the response and sketch.