# If $|x_{n+1} -x_n|<AC^n$ then $(x_n)$ is Cauchy

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, cauchy-sequences

Let ${x_n}$ be a sequence such that there exist $A>0$ and $C\in (0,1)$ for which $|x_{n+1} -x_n|<AC^n$, for any $n\geq 1$. Show that $\{x_n\} $ is Cauchy. Is this conclusion still valid if we assume only $\lim_{n\to\infty} |x_{n+1}-x_n|=0? $

Comment: Do you mean $AC^n$?

Comment: You need to show us your thoughts, your attempts.

Comment: Yes i mean $ AC^n$.

Comment: Okay, I have shown that $x_n$ is Cauchy. What now?

Comment: @GEDgar, i think we have to show that AC^n is less than epsilon, then we can make it to be cauchy

Comment: Look at the definition of "Cauchy".  It is not just that $|x_{n+1}-x_n|$ is small.

Comment: @GEDgar Yes i know. We can add x_m and subtract x_m

Comment: For the last part, see: 
[Is a bounded sequence such that $\lim(a_{n+1}-a_n)=0$ necessarily Cauchy?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/768404/boundedness-and-cauchy-sequence-is-a-bounded-sequence-such-that-lima-n1-a) and [An example of a bounded pseudo Cauchy sequence that diverges?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/528753/an-example-of-a-bounded-pseudo-cauchy-sequence-that-diverges) and [Pseudo-Cauchy sequence](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1237655).

Comment: And the first part is rather similar to this: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/661047/cauchy-sequences-involving-geometric-series or http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/572635/analysis-question-cauchy-sequence

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note, that for $m > n$, we have 
\begin{align*}
  \def\abs#1{\left|#1\right|}\abs{x_m - x_n}&= \abs{\sum_{k=n}^{m-1} x_{k+1} - x_k}\\
  &\le \sum_{k=n}^{m-1}\abs{x_{k+1} - x_k}\\
 &\le A \sum_{k=n}^{m-1} C^k\\
  &= AC^n \sum_{k=0}^{m-n-1} C^k\\
  &= AC^n \frac{C^{m-n} - 1}{C - 1}\\
  &\le \frac{AC^n}{1-C}\\
  &\to 0, n \to \infty.
\end{align*}
For your additional question, have a look at $x_n = \sum_{k=1}^n \frac 1k$.

Comment: That mean just if x $x_n=\sum 1/k $ it will be true? Thank